# What anime is this image of a girl taking off a headset from?

Tags: rail-wars

I have absolutely no idea where she is from, but I'm looking for an anime to watch, this seems like it would be okay.

[image: Girl taking off headset.]
(click for animated version)

Answer (score 4):

I looked at the original GIF and ran a [Google Image search](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/793/2604) at a few points when the girl looks into the "camera". One of the results that came up suggested that this is from the anime adaptation of [Rail Wars!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_Wars!), which follows a continuity where the Japanese national railway system was never privatised. (Here's the [MyAnimeList link](http://myanimelist.net/anime/23309/Rail_Wars!) as well.) The anime just started airing, and is from a franchise based on a light novel series.

[image]

The protagonist is a boy named Takayama who wants to work for the railway, and who ends up having to work against a bunch of extremists (called RJ) who want privatisation.

The character in this image should be [Aoi Sakurai](http://myanimelist.net/character/105161/Aoi_Sakurai) (who seems to also be a high school student) - and she should be the same girl in this cover scan from Wikipedia.

Comment: OP's gif shows up around 08:30 in episode 1.

Comment: This is indeed Rail Wars. I only just started watching it too.